# Connect to a Server from my AWS EC2 instance

Tags: linux, mysql, amazon-ec2, ip, database-connection

I have a app running on AWS EC2 which connects to a database in another server. The database connection Uri is as following,

```
jdbc:XXX:172.18.2.107:3306/database
```

This is what I got form my networking team, I can connect to the database from the internal network. Network team has cleared the security on this for the incomings form the AWS IP.

But I still could not connect to the database. According to what I have read so far, I think this Uri not static. It is a private network ip address.

I would really appreciate if someone help me to get an idea on this matter.

Thanks

Comment: yes it is a private IP.  you need to set up a VPN from your AWS VPC to your server site. a temporary setup can be done with ssh.

Comment: @Skaperen Thanks, If you can add this answer, I can accept this.